# purpose of installing a perl module with apt-get instead of cpan

Tags: perl, debian, perl-module

While loading necessities into my [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton), *apt-get* recommended that I install [libtemplate-perl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libtemplate-perl). This seemed a jolly idea, and I obeyed.

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127566/an-explanation-of-the-nginx-starman-dancer-web-stack), I see a fellow traveler install [Plack](http://plackperl.org/) and [Starman](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Starman-0.4009/lib/Starman.pm) via *CPAN*, but then use *apt-get* to install [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/).

Minutes before reading said answer, I had installed *Dancer* via *CPAN*. And it had worked. It had worked real good!

What happens differently when I install  a *CPAN* package via a non-*CPAN* package manager? Are there pitfalls I need to be wary of because my *libtemplate-perl* came from *apt-get*, or my *Dancer* came from *CPAN*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Debian or Debian based distros like Ubuntu, `CPAN` (`/usr/bin/cpan` utility) installs modules into `/usr/local/lib/` by default. And Debian packages keep their files in `/usr/share/perl5/` and `/usr/lib/perl5/`.

It's a better way to choose [dh-make-perl](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edam/DhMakePerl-0.72/dh-make-perl) tool to package any `CPAN` distribution not available in your apt repositories, to **avoid making mess (serious risk of conflict between `apt` and `CPAN`)**:

```
dh-make-perl --build --cpan Some::Module
dpkg -i some-module*.deb
```

Also check out about [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib#NAME) and [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/).

Comment: A short, correct answer with bonus information -- the best!

Answer (score 7):

A lot of tutorials, Stack Overflow answers, walk throughs, etc. will not want to assume that you know how to use /usr/bin/cpan and will instead suggest that you use your system's package manager, which you are more likely to be familiar with.

This is especially true if you are using a tool written in a particular language, but you don't know that language. For example many people wouldn't care whether crouton is written in Perl, Python or Lisp, they just want a tool they can use. Your average Debian or Ubuntu user is more likely to be familiar with apt-get than with cpan.

If you are looking to program in Perl I recommend installing things by cpan, using [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) and/or [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib). If you are just looking to install a tool you can use, I would recommend using apt-get.

---

Additionally apt-get has the advantage that non-Perl dependencies will be installed automatically. For example the CPAN module [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) requires that the libxml2 headers are available on the system; the CPAN distribution has no way of stating that as a dependency, and will simply fail on install if it can find the headers to link against. The Debian package can actually specify that libxml2 is a dependency, and will install the dependency automatically for you.

Despite that if you are looking to use XML::LibXML as a Perl programmer, I would recommend installing it with cpan and installing the libxml2 package via apt-get. Having all your Perl modules installed in the same place - again, via perlbrew or local::lib - will help you keep your sanity in the future. CPAN is preferable to apt-get in this case because not all distributions have been packaged for Debian, and so you get a lot more options if you use CPAN directly.

---

In summary: [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Another difference to mention that I don't see in other answers, is that if you use CPAN to install a module then the module version you get will be set, until you decide to upgrade that module. Whereas, if you use apt and a later version appears in Debian at some point in the future, then `apt-get upgrade` will update it.

Maybe you want that, maybe you don't. It's neither necessarily an advantage, nor a disadvantage. Simply a difference to be noted.

Answer (score 1):

The good things about apt-get are

- that you can uninstall the packages afterwards should you need to
- if you are maintaining any number of servers it is quicker to use apt-get as there is no building required
- there are definite versions of packages which are tested for compatibility

The downsides are

- not necessarily the latest version of packages
- not all packages are available

Answer (score 0):

apt-get installs are generally easier and better than cpan because of dependencies alone.

If you are so lucky as to need SOAP::Lite, for example, it is many dozens of dependencies, and a one-line "apt-get install libsoap-lite-perl".

It is sometimes not clear how Perl CPAN names map to their repository package names, but "apt-cache search " is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, that can be used **for any distro in HOME install as simple user**:

## Pros

- avoid conflicts
- up to date version of perl and modules
- when you reinstall, you keep your home/perl as-si
- you can upgrade all installed modules with `$ cpan -r`

## Cons

- you need to upgrade Perl manually

## How to

Edit `~/.bashrc` or such, and add:

```
export PERL5LIB=~/localperl/lib/
export PATH=~/localperl/bin:$PATH
```

Then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Install latest Perl5 from sources: https://www.cpan.org/src/README.html

Now, you have an isolate Perl installation in your home.

Enjoy the power to install any libs via:

```
$ cpan -i Whatever::Module
```